# Stripe Subscription Testing

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a monthly subscription with stripe.

I wrote a sample code like that

```
            if event_type == 'checkout.session.completed':
            # Payment is successful and the subscription is created.
            # You should provision the subscription and save the customer ID to your database.
            try:
                session = stripe.checkout.Session.retrieve(
                    event['data']['object'].id, expand=['line_items', 'subscription'])
                _current_period_end = session['subscription']['current_period_end']
                _current_period_start = session['subscription']['current_period_start']
                _product_id = session['subscription']['items']['data'][0]['plan']['product']
                _user_id = session['client_reference_id']
                _stripe_customer_id = session['customer']
                _subscription_id = session["subscription"]['id']
                '''
                do other things to update user package
                '''

            except Exception as e:
                '''
                error log
                '''
        elif event_type == 'invoice.paid':

                if THIS_IS_NOT_FIRST_TIME:
                    parse_event_data
                    '''
                    do other things to extend subscription
                    '''
```

I have some questions;

1. I parsed web hook result from a dict which is returned from stripe.checkout.Session.retrieve object. It seemed a little bit odd to me. What if stripe update his API response and use a different names for dict keys that i used? Is there another way to get these values such as with dot notation maybe (session.get.product_id)?
2. How can i understand that invoice.paid event not triggered for the first time of subscription?
3. I want to test renewal process of my monthly subscription. I used stripe trigger invoice.payment_succeeded but i need a real data for my test accounts (with a test customer, subscription, product etc...)
4. I can update my user package with using CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID
   from checkout success url ("success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}). Should i do that or use checkout.session.completed web hook?
5. I have just returned HTTP 500 response to every request to my webhook URL to see if STRIPE show an error message to user in checkout page. However, STRIPE just created a successful subscription. In that case, STRIPE will take a payment from my customer, however even if i can not update my customer package on my database. What should i do to prevent this issue? Should i create a scheduled job to sync data between STRIPE and my db?

Answer (score 1):

You have many separate questions that would be better suited for Stripe's support team directly: https://support.stripe.com/contact/email

Now I will try to touch on some of the questions you had starting with the first one.

When you call `session = stripe.checkout.Session.retrieve(...)` you get back a class that is a Checkout `Session`. All the properties of the class map to the  properties covered in the API Reference for [Session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object). This means you can do `session.id` which is `cs_test_123` or `session.created` which is a timestamp of the creation date. It's not really different from accessing as a dictionary overall.

You're also asking if those can change and Stripe explains their backwards compatibility policy in details in their docs [here](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades). If they were to change a name from `created` to `created_at`, they would do it in a new API version for new integrations and it wouldn't impact your code unless you manually changed the API version for your account so that is safe.

For the `invoice.paid` event, you want to look at the invoice's `billing_reason` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-billing_reason) which would be `subscription_create` for the first invoice.

You can test all of this easily in Test mode, create a session, start a subscription, etc. You can also simulate cycle changes.

I hope this helps but chatting with their support team is your best bet since those are more integration questions and not coding questions.